hosting ReactJS views with Typescript inside ASP.NET MVC
I am trying to integrate React/Typescript into an existing ASP.NET MVC application. I know that it's kind of antipattern and best way to do this would be to keep the front and back end separate. i.e, ASP.NET Web API for backend and React on front end.
Since the application is quite large we just can't abandon the application altogether and move to React + Web API. So I looked into possible solutions and found that I can use ReactJS.net but the documentation is class based (old school) and not much support present for TSX in documentation.
Can someone guide me on the approach and how to proceed for now so that eventually we move into pure React/TypeScript and C# Web API architecture, but right now serve the React view inside Razor till we gradually make the migration?
I tried using the documentation/example provided on the ReactJS.Net and it works but couldn't achieve the same with TypeScript.

I'd have a ready-to-use base, but it uses MUI as graphical interface and WebPack. Is it okay for you? https://mui.com/
